# Alternate between Executing a MATLAB file and a Python script

Tags: python, bash, matlab, sh

I have a MATLAB file that currently saves its variables into a .mat workspace. The python script uses SciPy.io to read these variables from the workspace. The python script performs some operations & resaves variables into a MATLAB workspace(agin using Scipy.io) which matlab should then reopen. I'm using MATLABR2013a and I dont think there's an easy way to run the python script from within the .m file itself.

There may be an easier way then the method I'm going about doing it but my current plan is to create a bash script that runs the matlab file and only proceeds to the latter section if a random variable (stored in another file) is of a certain value. The script then calls the python script, sets the random variable to a different (can view as a sort of boolean). The matlab script will then execute the second section but not the first section. I need to have about 5 or 6 such exclusive sections however and it's easier to have them all in the same .m file than it is to separate them

This seems tedious however when all I really want is a way to have the system pause the matlab script, run the python script and come back to that spot in the matlab script.

Appreciate all creative suggestions to make this workflow as efficient as possible and easy to modify

Comment: It sounds like you should be calling the python from within matlab. You can do this using the [system](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html) command. Of course, this assumes that it is not possible to solve your entire problem in python or matlab. That would make things a lot more simple.

Comment: Yes, this is indeed the way I ended up doing. I'll make a post detailing all the steps I took in both Python and Matlab to implement this correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB code detailed below

1. I saved the workspace using MATLAB's save function
2. Used MATLAB's system() function to execute the python script.
3. Within python, used scipy.iosavemat to save variables I wanted to access in matlab
4. Used MATLAB's load function to load the variables from python back into matlab's workspace

   ```
   writeto=['insert path to save to here']
   save(writeto)
   first_Pypath=['insert path of python script here']
   py_call=horzcat('python ',first_Pypath);
   system(py_call);
   ```